# How could I made subclass inherit included module from parent in ruby?

Tags: ruby

How can I make subclasses inherit parent's include code directly, without having to include the same module all time?

For example:

```
class P
  include something
  ...
end

class C1
  include something
  ...
end

class C2
  include something
  ...
end
```

As it turns out I made a big mistake, this is not the cause of my bug....
Truly sorry asking a stupid question.... :(

Thank you guys~~

Comment: at least take the effort to denote that those are really subclasses...

Comment: You need to ask better questions, or the people will just downvote you.

Comment: please rephrase your question. I think what you are looking for,couldn't phrase it properly. It is very unclear what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

```
module Includable
end

class Parent
  include Includable
end

class ChildOne < Parent
end

class ChildTwo < Parent
end
```

Without having a clearer understanding of the question, this will simply inherit from the parent, and the parent includes the module, so the children take advantage of that.

Answer (score 1):

Subclasses automatically inherit parents included modules, you don't need to do anything extra.